# a question on algebraic intersection number between two loops on a surface

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, differential-topology

Define the algebraic intersection number between two simple closed curves $\alpha$ and $\beta$, denoted by $\#(\alpha,\beta)$,  in a surface by the sum of all indices of the points of intersections between $\alpha$ and $\beta$, where the index is +1 if the orientation of the pair $(\alpha,\beta)$ agrees with the orientation of the surface and -1 otherwise.

Let $\alpha_1,\alpha_2, \beta_1, \beta_2$ be simple closed curves in a surface $S$. Suppose $[\alpha_1]=[\alpha_2]$ and $[\beta_1]=[\beta_2]$ in the first homology group of $S$, $H_1(S)$. Then we obtain $\#(\alpha_1-\alpha_2,\beta_1-\beta_2)=0$. Does the latter imply that $\#(\alpha_1,\beta_1)-\#(\alpha_2,\beta_2)=0$?

Comment: So you are assuming that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are transverse and either smooth or piecewise-linear? But assuming you fix your typo (just before the end), intersection number is a homology invariant (check intersections with the boundary of a two-simplex), so $\#(\alpha_1,\beta_1)=\#(\alpha_2,\beta_1)=\#(\alpha_2,\beta_2)$. By the way # is a confusing notation, as it suggests counting points without regard for orientation. Maybe you should write $I(\alpha,\beta)$, or some such.

Comment: Sorry Shifrin, But is the implication true in my question, that's if $\#(\alpha_1-\alpha_2,\beta_1-\beta_2)=0$, then $\#(\alpha_1,\beta_1)-\#(\alpha_2,\beta_2)=0$

Comment: It does not follow from what you wrote. But you threw away information when you wrote "then we obtain ..." [This is similar to the proof in modular arithmetic that the products of equivalent numbers are equivalent. You can't do it your way.]

Comment: See Guillemin and Pollack "Differential Topology" for the proof that the algebraic intersection number depends only on the homology class.